# Would OLS be just as good as OLR for analyzing this survey?

Tags: regression, logistic, survey

I want to use a regression in survey analysis, to determine the extent to which a variety of **ordinal** (and a few **nominal**) independent variables predict a variety of **ordinal** dependent variables.

My understanding is (based on [this Laerd guide](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/ordinal-regression-using-spss-statistics.php)) that I can't use OLS, because the dependent variables are ordinal. Instead, I need to use Ordinal Logistic Regression (OLR), which can accept continuous, ordinal, or categorical variables as independent variables as long as the dependent variable is ordinal.

However, reading similar papers to the one I'm trying to write, I am not seeing much use of OLR for survey analysis. Instead, it seems like social scientists sometimes use OLS even when the dependent variable is actually categorical or ordinal. [This paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2056305119826120), for example, appears to be using OLS with a categorical dependent variable.

Is it ok or better to use OLS in my survey analysis, even though Laerd says one should not? Is it acceptable in the social sciences?

Some more details:

- I am using SPSS.
- My field is internet studies/communication.
- I have not yet checked all the assumptions for OLR, but I am working on it.
- I have about 500 data points.
- I am also looking for a non-linear regression technique that will work with my data, because I expect the participants' age to have a roughly parabolic effect on some of of my dependent variables. Tips on what to use are welcome.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should specify what your dependent variable is.  That's really the critical question.  Is it a scale made up from many Likert items?

Comment: The DV is the average (or sum) of Likert responses across 500 participants. Actually it's a bunch of different summed up seven-point Likert scales, but I'm planning to do a separate regression for each.

I've heard people talk about the use of OLS being acceptable when the DV is somehow an aggregate of Likerts, but I haven't heard an example of such an aggregate. To be an

Comment: As a caveat to this discussion, I'm not that well versed in the analysis of Likert scales...  If you are summing up Likert items into a scale, you are already assuming that the values in the item are interval in nature.  That is, it makes sense that a "1" and a "5" can add up to the same value as a "2" and a "4" only if you've assumed that these categories are equally spaced.  It is often that the scale values will follow the assumptions of OLS regression (e.g. relatively continuous, conditionally normal, or such that the central limit theorem allows for OLS).

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you!